# Is eating meals at irregular times unhealthy?

Tags: medical-science, nutrition

[Best Time to Eat Meals](http://energyfanatics.com/2008/10/13/best-time-eat-meals/)

> Skipping meals or eating meals on a random schedule can drain your body of energy

I tend to eat whenever I feel like it. I pretty much ignore breakfast, lunch, and dinner times. Is this unhealthy, as opposed to eating a set number of times per day at set times, and why? My parents tell me "it's healthier" to eat during set times of the day.

Comment: We want to focus our attention on doubtful claims that are widely held or are made by notable people.  Please [provide some references](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/882/what-are-the-attributes-of-a-good-question/883#883) to places where this claim is being made.

Comment: It would seem to me that many parents make this claim to children (like mine did). I can't cite 'them', but it's an important question to get straight. Most sites only mention specific advantages or disadvantages (e.g. eat at regular times to maintain constant blood sugar levels), but I'm looking for more / wider advantages and disadvantages. I added one of the sites I found.

Comment: Do others concur? Did you hear this from your parents? I never did, but I may be the outlier.

Comment: My roommates seem to think so. Then again, I can't find articles online strictly talking about this. But I'm sure there's more than one person who has the same curious question.

Comment: @Oddthinking - yes, it's a popular folk wisdom.

Comment: @Oddthinking I concur with DVK's concurrence.

Comment: @Oddthinking I third DVK and Iszi's concurrences. Moreover, I have heard this several times from friends in nutrition and sports-nutrition post-secondary programs, but they had never brought forth any documented research to support this argument. My personal experience suggests the opposite, but my perspective is neither generalizable nor unbiased (possibly due to unclear thinking brought about by non-standard eating cycles? Hmmm.)

Comment: Excellent. Notability established. Next step: Let's answer this baby!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I thought that we would have evolved with irregular meal-times, and the evidence would demonstrate the desire for regular meal-times was an "old wive's tale". I was surprised by the evidence, which does support the idea of regular meal-times.

## Energy after Eating

- H R Farshchi, M A Taylor and I A Macdonald,  [Decreased thermic effect of food after an irregular compared with a regular meal pattern in healthy lean women](http://www.nature.com/ijo/journal/v28/n5/abs/0802616a.html), International Journal of Obesity (2004) 28, 653–660. doi:10.1038/sj.ijo.0802616

Nine lean women were given regular meals and irregular diet with up to 9 meals per day.

> CONCLUSION: Irregular meal frequency led to a lower postprandial energy expenditure compared with the regular meal frequency, while the mean energy intake was not significantly different between the two. The reduced TEF with the irregular meal frequency may lead to weight gain in the long term.

(Note: The last sentence is speculation. They did not observe weight-gain during the trial.)

The same authors tried it again with obese women:

- Hamid R Farshchi, Moira A Taylor, and Ian A Macdonald, [Beneficial metabolic effects of regular meal frequency on dietary thermogenesis, insulin sensitivity, and fasting lipid profiles in healthy obese women](http://ajcn.nutrition.org/content/81/1/16.short), Am J Clin Nutr January 2005 vol. 81 no. 1 16-24.

Ten obese women were put on regular and irregular meal times for two weeks:

> Conclusion: Regular eating has beneficial effects on fasting lipid and postprandial insulin profiles and thermogenesis.

Some other studies show some less directly related, but still interesting, results:

## In Your Head

- [This study](http://psycnet.apa.org/journals/psp/10/2/98/) shows that "dinner time" hunger may be more about what time your head thinks it is, rather than the state of your stomach.

## Regular *Family* Meals

- Related to the idea of regular meals, is the idea of regular *family* meals. There are a [number of positive social effects](http://dev.srcprojecth.org/articles/family_table.pdf) related to regular family meals.
- In Finnish children, not having a regular family dinner  [is correlated](http://psycnet.apa.org/journals/psp/10/2/98/) to eating more sweets, more problematic behaviour and a lower socio-economic class. I would tentatively suggest the causation is more likely to flow from the socio-economic class towards the other items.
- In Minnesotan children, regular family meal times [was associated](http://europepmc.org/abstract/MED/19304252) with healthier eating five years later. Again, I suspect socio-economic class and education to be a confounding factor. ([Same authors](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1054139X04000503))

## Meal Frequency - Nibbling versus Gorging

Just because you have regular meal times, doesn't mean there aren't a lot of them throughout the day.

- Increased frequency (with the same total intake) [may reduce cholesterol](http://europepmc.org/abstract/MED/2674713).
- Increased frequency [may affect insulin secretion](http://europepmc.org/abstract/MED/2674713).
- However, [this study](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=879792) argues some of the weight-loss claims associated with increased frequency eating may be experimental artefacts.
- Increased frequency eating [helps athletes consume high-calory diets](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=879828)

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the thorough answer. I'm just curious as a side question - what sites or tools do you use to answer questions? What resources do you use? I was able to find 3 similar links using [Google Scholar Search](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=irregular+meal+times&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C5&as_sdtp=), but maybe you have some additional resources. This isn't just for this topic; it's for personal research in general.

Comment: @Jason: [Pubmed](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/) is what you should use for this sort of things (you may also want to try [GOPubmed](http://gopubmed.com/), which uses the same database but adds gene ontology filters to it).

Comment: On the first study and second, what they refer to as "irregular" pattern, is eating with randomized predetermined pattern, which I believe has the obvious conclusion that they got. I believe when people say they don't have regular eating time, it usually means eating when you feel hungry irrespective of wall time. I'm on the latter camp, in that I don't sync mealtime with daytime, not do I have a preset time to have a meal, but I let my body signal me when it needs to eat.

Comment: @Jason: I used Google Scholar, refining the search as I read some of the papers to get relevant terms. There is a meta-question on the subject of good sources.

Comment: @Lie: Interesting point. That makes the conclusions less useful. Thank you.